# What are all of Jessica's hangman papers and what do they say?

Tags: outlast-2

While progressing through Outlast 2, there are multiple times where you are taken to what appears to be another dimension of the Catholic school that Blake, Jessica, and Lynn attended.  During these "flashbacks" to the school, you will find pieces of paper with a hangman game left behind by Jessica such as this:

[image: Hangman note]

This one says presumably "Strangle," but some of them are rather difficult (at least to me) and are comprised of multiple words.

I believe that during each flashback, there is at least one paper to be found. What are all of the hangman papers, and what do they say?

Comment: UNFORGIVABLE,

Sounds about right.